# Import a CSV with columns as str and set

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to import a CSV with first column as `str`, and second as `set`. This works:

```
import pandas as pd, io
s = io.StringIO("""12,{'hello'}
                   34,"{'foo', 'bar'}"
                   """)
df = pd.read_csv(s, header=None, converters={0: str, 1: eval})
print(df)
print(type(df.iloc[0,0]), type(df.iloc[0,1]))  # OK: str and set
```

But when doing it with `index_col=0` to force to use column 0 as index, it does not work anymore:

```
s = io.StringIO("""12,{'hello'}
                   34,"{'foo', 'bar'}"
                   """)
df = pd.read_csv(s, header=None, converters={0: str, 1: eval}, index_col=0)
print(df)
for a, b in df[1].items():  # iterate on the series df[1]
    print(a, b)
    print(type(a), type(b))  # <class 'int'> <class 'set'>   instead of str and set!
```

Output:

```
             1
0             
12     {hello}
34  {bar, foo}

12 {'hello'}
<class 'int'> <class 'set'>
34 {'bar', 'foo'}
<class 'int'> <class 'set'>
```

**Why is the `str` conversion missing here?**

Comment: `read_csv` is so configurable that some combinations give unexpected results. Here I would not try to set the index at the time of reading but I would just use `set_index`: `df = pd.read_csv(s, header=None, converters={0: str, 1: eval}).set_index(0)`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Would you like to post this an an answer? I would accept it!

Comment: Please feel free to use my comment to post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @SergeBallesta in a comment, this is a short solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv(s, header=None, converters={0: str, 1: eval}).set_index(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you have set 0 as index, you need to change the datatype of the index column:

```
s = io.StringIO("""12,{'hello'}
               34,"{'foo', 'bar'}"
               """)
df = pd.read_csv(s, header=None, converters={0: str, 1: eval}, index_col=0)
df.index = df.index.astype(str)
for a, b in df[1].items():  # iterate on the series df[1]
    print(a, b)
    print(type(a), type(b))  # <class 'int'> <class 'set'>   instead of str and set!

12 {'hello'}
<class 'str'> <class 'set'>
34 {'foo', 'bar'}
<class 'str'> <class 'set'>
```

Comment: Thanks. So what happened to the `converters={0: str,`? It was not taken in consideration? Isn't there a way to do all of this directly in the `read_csv`, rather than having to use `astype` after?

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's a way to set the dtype of index col in `read_csv`.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the dataframe as it is and then convert the index to str with:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do everything inside the `read_csv` call, with proper parameters?